# jQuery doesn't parseInt blank input as 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var totalOwed = <?php echo $totalTally; ?>;

    $("#cash").keyup(function() { doThis(); });
    $("#card").keyup(function() { doThis(); });

    var paidSoFar = 0;


    function doThis() {
        paidSoFar = parseInt($("#cash").val()) + parseInt($("#card").val());
        alert(paidSoFar);
        if (paidSoFar >= totalOwed) { 
            endCalc = paidSoFar - totalOwed;
            $("#endCalc").html("Change: " + endCalc); 
        }
        else { 
            remaining = totalOwed - paidSoFar;
            $("#endCalc").html("Remaining: " + endCalc);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

HTML is as follows:

```
Total Owed: <?php echo $totalTally; ?><br />
Cash: <input type="text" id="cash" /><br />
Card: <input type="text" id="card" /><br />
<div id="endCalc"></div>
```

But the paidSoFar variable ends up as NaN when it tries to read the values of the text inputs.

---

### UDATE

Now, my Javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var totalOwed = <?php echo $totalTally; ?>;

    $("#cash").keyup(function() { doThis(); });
    $("#card").keyup(function() { doThis(); });

    var paidSoFar = 0;


    function doThis() {
        paidSoFar = parseInt($("#cash").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#card").val(), 10);
        alert(paidSoFar);
        if (paidSoFar >= totalOwed) { 
            endCalc = paidSoFar - totalOwed;
            $("#endCalc").html("Change: " + endCalc); 
        }
        else { 
            remaining = totalOwed - paidSoFar;
            $("#endCalc").html("Remaining: " + endCalc);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

And the HTML is as follows:

```
Total Owed: <?php echo $totalTally; ?><br />
Cash: <input type="text" id="cash" /><br />
Card: <input type="text" id="card" /><br />
<div id="endCalc"></div>
```

But the `paidSoFar` variable ends up as `NaN` when it tries to read the values of the text inputs.

Comment: if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) { doThis; } } doesn't actually call anything.  did you mean this: if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) { doThis(); } }.  Also, doThis = remaining(); takes the value returned by remaining and assigns it to doThis.  I'm assuming you want to assign the function itself, in which case it would be doThis = remaining

Comment: This is the weirdest code I've ever seen.

Comment: What the heck is `doThis`, and what makes you think you can just stick it in anywhere ?

Comment: messy code, please solve this issue first

Comment: Haha, I copied and pasted the keyup from another bit of code and it admittedly needs tidying. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AFTER UPDATE

You can use the unary operator. For example,

```
+$("#cash").val()
```

As in,

```
paidSoFar = (+$("#cash").val()) + (+$("#card").val());
```

---

### BEFORE UPDATE

To answer your question specifically without going into details of all the other problems. In the following lines of code.

```
function remaining() {
  ...
  if (paidSoFar >= totalOwed) {
    ...
  } else {
    remaining = totalOwed - paidSoFar;
    ...
  }
}
```

If you follow the usage of `remaining`, you can clearly see that you are overwriting `remaining` to a number. So, the next time you try to use `remaining()`, you may be getting the following error in your JavaScript console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function
```

And the following usage is also worrisome.

```
function remaining() {
    ...
    $("#changeOrRemaining").html(remaining);
    ...
}
```

This one is clearly an infinite loop.

Check [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) for details to access your browser's console.

Comment: I totally forgot that I'd used "remaining" as the function name. Thank you.

Comment: Aside from the orignal messy code, I think there was a problem with the text inputs. I've updated my question.

Comment: @rybo111, Aside from the original messy code, this problem has been solved countless times in [so]. Please search

Answer (score 0):

Check your console log in your browser (Firebug would be best). You're most likely running into an error below the alert and it stops all JavaScript from running after it gets the error.